# Как разместить элементы header горизонтально

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, angularjs

С помощью bootstrap работаю над header’ом своей страницы, но при добавлении форм элементы размещаются вертикально один над другим. Как сделать, чтобы и изображение бреднда и формы и кнопки размещались только горизонтально? 
(код на Angular)

```css
#circle {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: mediumblue;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.navbar-btn {
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

navbar navbar-header {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

li a {
  color: white;
}

li a:hover {
  color: khaki;
  background-color: midnightblue;
}

input {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar navbar-header col-lg-offset-1">
        <div id="circle" class="navbar-brand"></div>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputFirstName" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
            <label for="inputLastName" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Last Name">
          </div>
        </form>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-btn my-btn">Ввод</button>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right: 10%">
        <li><a href="#">О приложении</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Проекты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день!Так используйте bootstrap grid. В примере ниже вы получите 3 горизонтальных блока. 12 / 4 = 3

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-4"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Comment: angular то тут причем?

Comment: В случае если я делаю так как вы сказали, я получаю вертикальное расположение полей ввода в lg-breakpoint, а в md-breakpoint вся навигация растягивается по вертикали.

Answer (score 0):

В случае если я разбиваю весь header на две группы: 6 - слева и 5 - справа (1 - оффсет слева) у меня все равно уходит на следующий ряд элемент button.

```css
#circle {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: mediumblue;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
.navbar-btn
{
  margin-top: 12px;
}
navbar
{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.navbar navbar-header
{
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-inverse
{
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.form-inline
{
  margin-top: 13px;
  max-width: 350px;
}
li a  {
  color: white;
}
li a:hover{
  color: khaki;
  background-color: midnightblue;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="navbar navbar-header">
        <div id="circle" class="navbar-brand"></div>
      </div>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputFirstName" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
                <label for="inputLastName" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Last Name">
          </div>
        </form>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-btn my-btn">Ввод</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">О приложении</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Проекты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```